# How to find the remainder in a polynomial division, given remainders from other polynomial divisions

Tags: functions

Let $F(x)$ be a polynomial.

if F(x) is divided by $(x-1)^2$ the remainder will be x+1

and if F(x) is divided by $(x)^2$ the remainder will be 2x+3.

What is the remainder if F(x) is divided by $x^2$(x-1)?

---

my solution : 
F(x) = $(x-1)^2$ P(x) + x+1, substitute x=1 and get F(1) = 2

differentiate it and get F'(x) = $(x-1)^2$ P'(x)+P(x)(2)(x-1)+1 then F'(1)=1

and do the same to the other equation ( F(0)=3, F'(0) = 2 )

Let the remainder of F(x) divided by $x^2$(x-1) be R(x) ( R(x) = a$x^2$+bx+c)

so F(x) =$x^2$(x-1)A(x) + R(x)

F(0) = R(0) = 3

F(1) = R(1) = 2

F'(x) = $(x)^2$(x-1) A'(x)+$x^2$A(x)+2x(x-1)A(x) + R'(x)

F'(0) = R'(0) = 2

from R(0) = 3 then c=3

from R'(0) = 2 then R'(x) = 2ax+b then R'(0) = b = 2

R(x) = a$x^2$+2x+3 from R(1) = 2, will get a+5 = 2 , a=-3

so the remainder will be  -$3x^2$+2x+3

but from other solution in the comment section, the answer can be -3$x^2$+2x+1 too, so what's correct answer.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For typesetting, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Adding things like "please help" is unconstructive. You should add constructive information to your question e.g. is F given? If so, how did you get the remainders for the first two? If not, then are the remainders given? And what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

The first statement is equivalent to saying that the function F has the following form:
$F(x) = P_1(x)(x-1)^2 + (x+1)$

where $P_1(x)$ is some polynomial. Similarly the second statement is equivalent to saying that the function F has the following form:
$F(x) = P_2(x)x^2 + (2x+3)$

where $P_2(x)$ is some polynomial.

For simplicity proceed assuming that the degrees of F(x) are 3. (We don't know this to be true but it gets us to the same answer) This is feasible since dividing F by a degree 2 polynomial gives a degree one polynomial in both your expressions. This tells you that both $P_1(x)$ and $P_2(x)$ must be degree one polynomials, so you can write:
$P_1(x) = a_1 x+b_1$ and 
$P_2(x) = a_2 x+b_2$

Now you can substitute for both expressions for $F(x)$.

$F(x) =(a_1 x+b_1)(x-1)^2 + (x+1)$

$F(x) =(a_2 x+b_2)x^2 + (2x+1)$

Set both expressions equal to each other, and solve for the four constants. 
$(a_1 x+b_1)(x-1)^2 + (x+1) =(a_2 x+b_2)x^2 + (2x+1)$
$a_1=5, b_1=2, a_2=5, b_2=-8$

This should let you complete the solution to your problem.

Comment: You cannot say that $\deg F=3$. After all, adding a multiple of  $x^2(x-1)^2$ to $F$ changes nothing.

Comment: From your solution, I tried substituting both equation and I got 2 remainder answers


1. $-3x^2$ +2x +3


2.  $-3x^2$ +2x +1

which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

So 
$$ F(x)=x+1+g(x)(x-1)^2$$
and 
$$ F(x)=2x+3+h(x)x^2.$$
As $$(2x+1)(x-1)^2+(-2x+3)x^2=4x^2-1,$$
we conclude that
$$\begin{align}F(x)&= (2x+1)(x-1)^2F(x)+(-2x+3)x^2F(x)\\
&=(2x+1)(x-1)^2(2x+3)+h(x)x^2(x-1)^2\ +\ (-2x+3)x^2(x+1)+g(x)x^2(x-1)^2\\
\end{align}$$
To compute the remainder modulo $x^2(x-1)$, you can ignore thesummands involving $g$ and $h$.

Comment: i'm confused, how did you get this $$(2x+1)(x-1)^2+(-2x+3)x^2$$